# How to create sign with gmail in nodejs express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, gmail

I have my User model in mongoDB and I created an API for Sign-Up and Sign-In but also i want to create an API for sign-In with gmail so how can I create this ?

Comment: You want the integration with Google account system? Take a look at [Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

Comment: You can easly use Passport.